# Word for the moving part of a slider?

Tags: single-word-requests

An example for a slider is the scroll bar that lets us move down a long web page. A slider consists of a line and a thing that you can move along that line. What do you call the moving component of a slider?

Example sentence:
"For most sliders, if you click somewhere along the slider line, the ____ will jump to that position."

Comment: There is a scrollbar and a thumb aka scrollbox. That is what moves.

Comment: @Lambie If you submit that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I would call it "a meat patty".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although "**slider handle**" works too, its formal name is "**slider thumb**", which is the term of choice in the IT industry.

[Slider Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.slider):

> Represents a control that lets the user select from a range of values by moving a **Thumb** control along a Track.

Edit: Updated the link to the MS article.

Answer (score 3):

I just googled and found a term **[slider handle](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=slider%20handle%20image&client=ucweb-b-bookmark&biw=360&bih=518&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRxtuNkd3aAhXMPI8KHfGnBrgQ_AUIBSgA)** and its images.

[image]

Also, [Scroll box](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/scrollbo.htm)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As is often the case, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrollbar) provides us with just about everything we would ever want to know about the subject under discussion.

#### Scrollbars

In the case you are talking about (scrolling a web page) the control is indeed called a `scrollbar` and the little rectangle you grab and use for scrolling is called the `thumb`. On most scrollbars the thumb will jump to a specific spot when you click somewhere in the `track` (sometimes called the `trough`) of the scrollbar.

#### Sliders

johnlee's answer is correct about the `thumb` but he calls the scrollbar a `slider`, which isn't the same thing. A `slider` is a similar control which allows the user to select a value from a range of values by positioning the thumb along the slider. Most sliders exhibit similar thumb-jumping behavior when you click anywhere in the slider `track`.

#### It's complicated

Not surpisingly, Mac, Windows, and other GUI environments often have different names for these ubiquitous screen widgets, but the above terms seem to be fairly generic. So read the Wikipedia article and call them whatever you want to. :)

Comment: Well, I did not call the `scrollbar` a `slider`. They are **two different UI controls using different APIs and classes** though they look and behave in somewhat similar ways. Read Fadeaway's question more carefully, and you'll see that he or she was _**not** really asking about the **scrollbar**, **but** about the **slider**_, about which my answer was.

Comment: Actually, no. The questions starts by saying "An example for a slider is the scroll bar that lets us move down a long web page." That's actually not an example of a slider; it's an example of a scrollbar. But whatever.

Comment: Nope. You got it backwards. 1. The title unambiguously states "Word for the moving part of a **slider**", and Fadeaway mentions "slider" far more often throughout the question. 2. In the sentence "An example ... page", the OP does state that the scrollbar is an example of a slider and then goes on to describe the scrollbar. A mere description of an example of an example does *not* change the subject. 3.  Again, I did not call the `scrollbar` a `slider`. Would you point out where I did?